# How to display the coefficients of year fixed effect and cluster fixed effect in feols() in r?

Tags: r, regression

I am running a two-way fixed effects model using `feols()` in r as follows.

```
library(fixest)
model1 = feols(lshare ~ Treated|sector + year, data = df)
texreg(model1, digits = 3)
```

The outcome is the following: I was wondering if there's a way to display all the coefficients of year and sector fixed effects in the output table.

[image]